# How do I run an entire CPP file from another?

Tags: c++

Right guys, I'm in a serious pickle here.

I'm doing a 2D game for University and it doesn't have to be complicated by any means.  I have experience making games in C# XNA and am trying to use similar techniques.  The only difference I might have to you guys is that I'm using a game engine called S2D, written by my lecturer, which bears similarities to XNA.

Essentially my problem is that I have two header files (EscapeThePrison.h and Player.h) and three cpp files (main.cpp, World.cpp and Player.cpp) so far.

In main.cpp I simply have the entry point for the game.

EscapeThePrison.cpp is the only other file being run, however.  This file is supposed to (as of yet) draw a background.  This works.

Player.cpp is supposed to draw my player image, however it does not do this.  I even used cout to just output text to see if it's being run but my code is just derpy, but I get nothing.

Anyway I basically need to be able to run the entire player.cpp file so the damn thing will work.  Below is my code.

EscapeThePrison.h:

```
#include "S2D/S2D.h"
#include "Player.h"
using namespace S2D;

class EscapeThePrison : public Game
{
private:
    Vector2* BGPosition;
    Rect* BGRect;
    Texture2D* BGTexture;

public:
    EscapeThePrison(int argc, char* argv[]);
    virtual ~EscapeThePrison();
    void virtual LoadContent();
    void virtual Update(int elapsedTime);
    void virtual Draw(int elapsedTime);
};
```

Player.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "S2D\S2D.h"
using namespace S2D;


struct User
{
    Vector2* pos;
    Rect* rect;
    Texture2D* texture;

};


class Player
{

private:
    User* user;


public:
    Player(int argc, char*argv[]);
    virtual ~Player();
    void virtual LoadContent();
    void virtual Update(int elapsedTime);
    void virtual Draw(int elapsedTime);

};
```

Main.cpp(entry for game)

```
#include "EscapeThePrison.h"
#include "Player.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    EscapeThePrison* game = new EscapeThePrison(argc, argv);

}
```

World.cpp (the working file)

```
#pragma once
#include "EscapeThePrison.h"
#include "Player.h"

EscapeThePrison::EscapeThePrison(int argc, char*argv[]) : Game(argc, argv)
{
    Graphics::Initialise(argc, argv, this, 1080, 720 , false, 25, 25, "EscapeThePrison", 60);
    Input::Initialise();
    Graphics::StartGameLoop();

}

EscapeThePrison::~EscapeThePrison()
{
    delete BGTexture;
    delete BGRect;
}

void EscapeThePrison:: LoadContent()
{
    BGTexture = new Texture2D();
    BGTexture->Load("Images/tiles.jpg", false);
    BGPosition = new Vector2(0.0f,0.0f);
    BGRect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 1080, 720);
}

void EscapeThePrison:: Update(int elapsedTime)
{

}

void EscapeThePrison:: Draw(int elapsedTime)
{
    SpriteBatch::BeginDraw();
    SpriteBatch::Draw(BGTexture, BGPosition, BGRect);

    SpriteBatch::EndDraw();

}
```

Player.cpp (the non-working one)

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Player::Player(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    user = new User();
}

Player::~Player()
{
    delete user->texture;
    delete user->rect;
}

void Player:: LoadContent()
{
    user->texture = new Texture2D();
    user->texture->Load("Images/PlayerImage.png", false);
    user->pos = new Vector2(100.0f, 100.0f);
    user->rect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 39, 79);
}

void Player:: Update(int elapsedTime)
{
    cout<< "output";
}

void Player:: Draw(int elapsedTime)
{
    SpriteBatch::BeginDraw();
    SpriteBatch::Draw(user->texture, user->pos, user->rect);
    SpriteBatch::EndDraw();
}
```

Right, now the code is out of the way, I'll tell you about what I've tried.

I contacted my lecturer about it and all he managed to say without being specific was pretty much 'use Player->Update();' which I tried but Intellisense highlights the '->' and says it expected an identifier.

Acting on *initiative* I tried using 'Player::Update();' but it told me I can't reference it from a static context.  I removed the brackets and it allowed it, but building the application still did nothing.

I'm also not a complete idiot and I made user the player wasn't being drawn behind the background by commenting out the draw code for the background.  Still nothing.

I really need help with this so no sarcastic answers please.  Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: You don't "run a .cpp file"

Comment: It's unclear where your instance of a `Player` is. Can you show that, and where you are trying to call `Update`?

Comment: `Player new_player(argc, argv); new_player.update()`??

Comment: I want to run the code in it though, which isn't being done.  All of it needs to be running all of the time.

Comment: "I made user" -- You what?

Comment: While not your original problem; EscapeThePrison.h and Player.h  "#include "S2D/S2D.h"" and #include "S2D\S2D.h". Pretty sure that is an error. I also don't think it's a good idea to include a \ in a filename anyway.

Comment: xphill64x, the #include "S2D/S2D.h" is how the S2D frampework is written.  The project folder contains a folder called S2D where S2D.h is residing.

Comment: Oh; that's a relative path. Got it. Why is one / and the other \ ?

Comment: @xphill64x: One is correct for Windows, the other is generalised. The OP should pick one or the other for consistency, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I derp sometimes with stuff like that.  Good to know it doesn't matter though.

Comment: @user3152015: It'll matter when you stop programming on Windows, or possibly if you change compiler versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call update on an instance of Player, not the Player class

Comment: So would that mean calling 'user->Update();'?

Comment: No. user is a member of your Player class. You make an instance/pointer of Player with Player* mainPlayer = new Player(argc, argv). Do this somewhere higher up, like in your EscapeThePrison class. Then, you can do things like mainPlayer->Update();

Comment: `Player* mainPlayer = new Player(int argc, char* argv[])` is not valid C++.

Comment: Always glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 4):

**You don't have any code to create a `Player`, or invoke functions on it**; you will need to add that code. Functions don't just magically get called autonomously on non-existent objects.

By the way, you are breaking [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) so your classes all have destructive/dangerous double-free bugs. Either add copy constructors or, better yet, drop all of this manual dynamic allocation.

> I contacted my lecturer about it and all he managed to say without being specific was pretty much 'use Player->Update();' *[..]* I removed the brackets and it allowed it, but building the application still did nothing

Programming by guessing doesn't work. Contact your professor again and this time have more than a three-line email conversation with him: sit down for half an hour or more, and have him explain to you how to structure your C++ program. That's what he's paid for.

Comment: The code for the Player is pretty much the same as the Background, but with a struct on it.  How did I create the background.

Comment: @user3152015: What is "Background"? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: Sadly I can't speak until tomorrow, so I came here :/ background is represented by BGText, BGpos and is drawn in the World::Draw()

Comment: There is no `World::Draw()`, either. You're being very imprecise. :( And please don't post on SO just because you're in a rush! SO is not a helpdesk. I hope you succeed at this but really this is not a good question for a Q&A knowledge base. You require mentoring/tutoring through this.

Comment: By World::Draw I meant the Draw method in World.cpp.  It isn't even that I'm in a rush, I have plenty of time realistically.  I just wanted to know the better way of doing this.

Comment: So you mean `EscapeThePrison::Draw()` (ignore the filenames - they are not important). We can't see what `Graphics::StartGameLoop()` does but presumably it invokes `EscapeThePrison::Draw()` in a loop. What it doesn't do is anything with any `Player` instances, which is your problem.

Comment: Well S2D is almost the same as XNA.  With XNA you have to declare each cs file as a drawable game object which needs a graphics device to be declared in order for Draw to be invoked.  S2D needs Graphics::Initialise and the likes to be able to draw, but in turn Graphics::Initialise needs the file to be initialised as a game *(EscapeThePrison::EscapeThePrison(int argc, char*argv[]) : Game(argc, argv)*.  My lecturer said I shouldn't have to declare Player.cpp as a game but unfortunately I can't seem to see any way to declare it as a game object.

Comment: Stop talking about files. Stop mentioning filenames. They are _totally_ irrelevant. It is not possible to "declare Player.cpp" or "run a .cpp file". Talk about class names, instead.